Oscillation in inrush current load switch
I have the switch in the picture and I've measured an oscillatory behavior while it's switching ON. The idea of the circuit is to avoid the large inrush current to charge the EMI filter by slowing down the switching on. The current source made of Q1 and R6 charges the S-G (C2) and D-G (C3) capacitors with a constant current of around 1mA. When the S-G voltage reaches the MOSFET threshold voltage (around 2.5V), it starts driving current and its drain voltage should rise with a constant slope mainly defined by the value of C3 and the Q1 current.
What I have measured is an oscillation in the MOSFET Vgs while it's in the Miller's plateau. In that moment, MOSFET's drain current has a kind of sawtooth waveform and the drain voltage, which should rise in around 2ms, rises much slower, up to 10ms.
I haven't got to reproduce this behavior in simulation. Any ideas of what could cause this oscillation?
Waveform:
CH1: on commmand
CH2: source current
CH3: drain voltage



What are the lengths of the physical loops formed between M1/C2 and M1/C3?

You should show the waveforms ...

I just edited the original post to add the waveforms

What are the "specs" of XMR1? This specifies somewhat the timing of "oscillation".

At your observed osc frequency estimating from your waveforms L1 has significant impedance. Damp out L1 with RC so drain impedance is lower and more real. Also give the p-channel MOSFET a gate resistor to damp out gate parasitics. Remember that you are running the MOSFET in linear mode for an eternity during the start up phase. PWM would be safer. You could give the MOSFET a fast freewheel diode like say UF4007 and remove C2,C3. Now you can put some slow PWM on the on/off pin.

It seems that oscillation (simulation) on MOSFET Vgs is "subject" to XFMR value.
Made with microcap v12

With a change in XFMR values ... 5 mH.


XFMR is a 2.6mH common mode choke with around 10uH of leakage.
